# Prove: If $a \in \mathbb{Q}^*$ has a square root in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for all primes $p$, then it has a square root in $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, p-adic-number-theory

I'm seeking to prove or disprove the following statement:
If $a \in \mathbb{Q}^*$ has a square root in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for all primes $p$, then it has a square root in $\mathbb{Q}$. (It is not assumed that $a$ has a root in $\mathbb{R}$).

Now from much trial and error I think this statement is true.

If $a$ is positive and there is some $x \in \mathbb{Q}_p$ such that $x^2 = a$ for all primes $p$ then by considering norms it follows that each power of $p$ in $a$ occurs with even exponent, and so we can clearly find a square root of $a$ in $\mathbb{Q}$.

However this doesn't work when $a$ is negative - how can we get a root of $a$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ in this case?

Comment: If $a$ is not a square then either $a= p^{2k+1} u/v$   with $p\nmid uv$ or $a=-b^2$, and $-1$ is not a square in $\Bbb{Q}_3$.

Comment: thanks for your comment - however I don't understand how this helps with the question. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Do I need to ? You solved the first case, for the second one use that $-1$ is not a square in $\Bbb{F}_3$ thus in $\Bbb{Q}_3$

Comment: Ah, I understand now! Thank you.